# MySQL find transactions (payments) of customers that have not purchased for the first time

Tags: mysql, payment

I have a simple table with transactions in it and I want to get, for each month, how many consumers made transactions that total more than 0 and their first transaction was not in that month. By first transaction we mean that the customer bought for the first time during that month.

The result I am trying to get is in the following form:

```
+--------+---------+-----------------------------------+
|  Year  |  Month  |  NumOfCustomersWithPositiveTotals |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------+
|  2014  |    1    |                 22                |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------+
|  2014  |    2    |                 10                |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------+
```

I've got an SQL fiddle where I find the same thing, but for consumers that have their first transactions within that month. Practically, the query I am looking for is the same, but for the rest of the consumers.

This is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31538/24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below returns the correct results. The answer was based on Akis's answer by adding the consumerId in the `group by` clause and adding years in the checks as well as months.

```
select
    tyyyy, tmm, count(tcon) as oldkund_real
from
(
    select
        t.yyyy as tyyyy, t.mm as tmm, t.consumerId as tcon, sum(t.amount) as total, fp.yyyy as fpyyyy, fp.mm as fpmm, fp.consumerId as fpcon
    from
        (
            select
                year(date) as yyyy, month(date) as mm, consumerId, amount
            from
                transaction
        ) as t
        left join
        (
            select
                year(min(date)) as yyyy, month(min(date)) as mm, consumerId
            from
                transaction
            group by
                consumerid
        ) as fp
        on
            t.consumerId = fp.consumerId
        group by
            t.yyyy, t.mm, t.consumerId
        having
            STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01,', tmm, ',', tyyyy),'%d,%m,%Y') > STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01,', fpmm, ',', fpyyyy),'%d,%m,%Y') and total > 0
) as res
group by
    tyyyy, tmm
order by
    tyyyy, tmm;
```

Thank you very much Akis!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT count(consumerId) as NumOfCust, mm, yy FROM
(
    SELECT consumerId, month(date) as mm, year(date) as yy, sum(amount) as total, mdate FROM beta.transaction as t
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT min(month(date)) as mdate, consumerId as con FROM beta.transaction
            GROUP BY consumerId
            ) as MinDate ON con = t.consumerId
    GROUP BY month(date), consumerId
    HAVING mdate < mm AND total > 0
) as res
GROUP BY res.mm;
```

And i will try to explain it from inside out

Let's see what the JOIN table named minDate has:

```
SELECT min(month(date)) as mdate, consumerId as con FROM beta.transaction
GROUP BY consumerId

-- Here we find the first date of transaction per consumerId
```

Next

```
SELECT consumerId, month(date) as mm, year(date) as yy, sum(amount), mdate FROM beta.transaction as t
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT min(month(date)) as mdate, consumerId as con FROM beta.transaction
            GROUP BY consumerId
            ) as MinDate ON con = t.consumerId
    GROUP BY month(date), consumerId
    HAVING mdate < mm AND total > 0

 -- Here we find total amount per consumerId per month and count only the consumers whose first transact (aka minDate) is lower than current month AND total is greater than 0
```

At last with the outer SELECT we count the above results Grouped by month. 
I hope its what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I changed your query a bit and I posted an answer below that does what I need.